# Syncfusion Grid, Move toolbar on bottom (Angular)

Tags: angular, grid, toolbar, syncfusion

Can I change the default position of the toolbar from the top to the bottom in a Child Grid?

I find this: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/grid/tool-bar/#add-toolbar-at-the-bottom-of-grid

but it is for Javascript and my childGrid is not a Grid, but a GridModel:

````
let childGrid: GridModel = {
      dataSource: data
      queryString: 'FId',
      columns: [
          { field: 'description', headerText: 'Description', textAlign: 'Left', width: '50%' },
          { field: 'qty', headerText: 'Qtà', editType:'numericedit',  textAlign: 'Left', width: 20 },
          { field: 'width', headerText: 'Lar', editType:'numericedit', textAlign: 'Left', width: 20 },
          { field: 'length', headerText: 'Lun', editType:'numericedit', textAlign: 'Left', width: 20 },
          { field: 'height', headerText: 'Alt', editType:'numericedit', textAlign: 'Left', width: 20 },
          { headerText:'', width:20, commands: [{ type: 'Edit', buttonOption: { cssClass: 'e-flat', iconCss: 'e-edit e-icons' } },
                                                     { type: 'Delete', buttonOption: { cssClass: 'e-flat', iconCss: 'e-delete e-icons' } },
                                                     { type: 'Save', buttonOption: { cssClass: 'e-flat', iconCss: 'e-update e-icons' } },
                                                     { type: 'Cancel', buttonOption: { cssClass: 'e-flat', iconCss: 'e-cancel-icon e-icons' }}]
          },          
      ],
      editSettings: { allowEditing: true, allowAdding: true, allowDeleting: true, newRowPosition: 'Bottom', showDeleteConfirmDialog: true},
      toolbar: ['Add'],
      allowRowDragAndDrop: true,
    }; ```

Thanks
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the requirement of changing the default position of child Grid’s toolbar element from top to bottom by using the parent Grid’s detailDataBound event(Triggers on initial parent row expand action). In this event the child Grid element will be returned as event arguments with which the toolbar position can be changed.

This is demonstrated in the below code snippet,

```
// Parent Grid’s detailDataBound event handler
detailDataBound(args) {
  // Current expanded child Grid element is retrieved
  let childGridEle = args.detailElement.querySelector('.e-grid');
  // Child Grid’s toolbar element is retrieved
  let toolbarEle = childGridEle.querySelector('.e-toolbar');
  // The toolbar element is appended as the last child of the child Grid
  childGridEle.appendChild(toolbarEle)
}
```

Please check the below sample prepared sample on this for your reference,

**Sample:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xevhjk?file=app.component.ts